# ExtJS 4 "always on top" Window

Tags: extjs

I need to implement Window which can be always on top. How can I to do it? All my tries with WindowManager give me no results :(

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053847/how-to-make-a-full-modal-window-in-ext-4

Comment: Take a look at `Ext.ZIndexManager.bringToFront()` method

Comment: Check this. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.window.Window.html#cfg-alwaysOnTop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ext.window.Window, there's a property called '*modal*': set it to true.

Otherwise, use the **WindowManager** to manage your windows: in this case you have to follow the following steps:

1. **register** your windows to the WindowManager (*Ext.WindowManager.register (winId)*)
2. use **bringToFront** method to set your window on top (*Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront (winId)*)
3. finally, check the element on top with the **getActive** method (*Ext.WindowManager.getActive ()*)

E.g.:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Your window' ,
  width: 300 ,
  height: 300 ,
  html: 'ciao ciao' ,
  modal: true
}).show ();
```

Or:

```
var win1 = Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Your window' ,
  id: 'firstWin' ,
  width: 300 ,
  height: 300 ,
  html: 'ciao ciao' ,
});
win1.showAt (50, 50);

var win2 = Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Your window' ,
  id: 'secondWin' ,
  width: 300 ,
  height: 300 ,
  html: 'I love pizza' ,
});
win2.showAt (60, 60);

// Register your floating objects (window in this case) to the WindowManager
Ext.WindowManager.register (win1);
Ext.WindowManager.register (win2);

// Bring 'firstWin' on top
Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront ('firstWin');

// Then, check the zIndexStack
alert (Ext.WindowManager.getActive().getId ()); // this is firstWin, the window with the highest zIndex
```

Hope this help you.

Cyaz

Comment: That's nice, and the **main question** is: **HOW** to detect that new window is showed over the my window?

Comment: Ah, now I got it ;) Well, first you have to register your windows to the WindowManager. Then, check the zIndexStack of the WindowManager ;) The first element of the stack is that with the highest zIndex.
Ext.WindowManager.zIndexStack[0] is your solution but I think the same thing should be done by Ext.WindowManager.getActive() but in my experiments it doesn't work...

Now look to my first answer with the entire solution: it's just edited ;)

Comment: Ok, I just understood how to get the window with the highest zIndex through Ext.WindowManager.getActive(): instead of using toFront() method of each windows, you have to use Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront(id/object) and then check it with Ext.WindowManager.getActive() ;) Look to the edited solution. Ciao!

Comment: `Ext.WindowManager.zIndexStack[0]` is the most bottom component. It is the last element of the array, which is given by `getActive()`.

Comment: this is bad onTop isn't the same that modal :D